# Azure Devops REST API: Publish test results including test steps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-api-management

community.
I want to publish my automation tests execution to DevOps Azure. The issue is that I cannot find the needed Request body that contains not only the status for the Test Case but also for each test step.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To add outcome to a test step, you need to send a [Results - Update request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update).
In the request body you have the iterationDetails property, that contains the array of actionResults. Each element of this array represents a test step. You can update the outcome of each test step by explicitly setting the "outcome" property.